# Remove Chatter options from a salesforce record page

Tags: chatter

Can we remove Post, File, Link, Vote etc chatter options for a custom object record page?

I am not talking about hiding this options by Show Feeds/Hide Feeds toggles. I just want to remove those options

Comment: is it lightning or classic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, go to the [Page Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutcustomize_pd.htm&type=5) for the object, and then remove everything you don't want in the "Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher" area.

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Feed Tracking in Setup under Chatter, Select the object and uncheck the Enable Feed Tracking at the top.

This will remove it from all page layouts under the object. If you only want it off a specific page layout you will need to recreate the layout and make sure the enable feed is unchecked upon creation. Once this is checked you can't uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lightning, then you can use App builder to remove chatter component from Lightning Page(Flexi Page)